# How do you avoid specifying template parameter for classes?

Tags: c++, templates

SFML's implementation of [Vector2](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/Vector2_8hpp_source.php) allows the following syntax:

```
sf::Vector2f v1(16.5f, 24.f);
sf::Vector2f v2 = v1 * 5.f;
sf::Vector2f v3;
```

...meaning that you don't have to specify the template parameter when creating an object. I'm trying to reproduce this code for my own purposes but am unable to see how it works. Here's what it looks like:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector2
{
public :

  Vector2();

  Vector2(T X, T Y);

  template <typename U>
  explicit Vector2(const Vector2<U>& vector);

  // Member data
  T x;
  T y;
};
```

And what my attempt looks like:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<
                                 std::is_same<T, int>::value 
                              || std::is_same<T, float>::value, T>::type>
struct Point
{
    T x, y;

    Point(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y)
    {
    }

    template <typename U>
    explicit Point(const Point<U>& point)
        : x(point.x), y(point.y)
    {
    }
};
```

But I still get an error 'missing template parameters'. What is SFML doing that I'm not?

Comment: I'm guessing SFML does this - `typedef Vector2<float> Vector2f;`. You can do the same with your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source file you link, note this line near the bottom:

```
typedef Vector2<float> Vector2f;
```

This is creating an alias of the `Vector2<float>` type as `Vector2f` -- they are the same type, just usable by different names.

You could do the same thing:

```
typedef Point<float> Pointf;
typedef Point<int> Pointi;
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is done via a `typedef`:

```
typedef Vector2<float> Vector2f;
```

or a *type alias*:

```
using Vector2f = Vector2<float>;
```

The latter is not valid before C++11.